# How to generate a number of n-bit in length using python?

Tags: python, random, python-2.7

Looking at the various [random functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) in the standard library, there isn't a way to generate numbers of *n-bit* length long.

Is there any efficient function I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.getrandbits(10)
688L
```

Comment: D'oh how did I miss that one......

Comment: I think the result is not exactly `n-bit`.

Comment: @Lisbeth what do you mean?

Comment: try this: print [len(bin(a)[2:]) for a in [random.getrandbits(100) for _ in range(10)]]

Comment: The correct one is: `print [len(bin(a)[2:]) for a in [getRandomNBitInteger(100) for _ in range(10)]]`

Comment: @jamylak Please see here: https://asciinema.org/a/y9VVZV0ExLdDmnNXBkyojcUXv

Comment: @Lisbeth Okay i see what you are trying to say now. However this result is `n-bit`, the reason why you could do `len(bin(688L))` and it says `12` is because it is represented as a `long` and the initial bits are all `0`s therefore they won't show in the `bin` representation. It could be any number up to `n-bit` length so `random.getrandbits(2))` could be `0`, `1`, or `2` or `3`. 0 would be `0b0` which is equivalent to `0b00`, 1 would be `0b1` equivalent to `0b01` and 2, `0b10` and 3, `0b11` they are still all `n-bit` numbers where `n` = 2 although they don't show the initial `0`s in `bin` rep

Comment: @Lisbeth I looked up your function and it returns a number in range `2**(N-1) and (2**N)-1.` which I understand is a different definition of it being only the numbers that would take up `N-bit` without including initial `0` bits. https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Util.number-module.html#getRandomNBitInteger

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.getrandbits(1)
0L
>>> random.getrandbits(100)
31456252575598781139680104123L
>>> help(random.getrandbits)
Help on built-in function getrandbits:

getrandbits(...)
    getrandbits(k) -> x.  Generates a long int with k random bits.
```

From the docs:

> **random.getrandbits(k)**
>   Returns a python long int with `k` random bits. This method is supplied with the MersenneTwister generator and some other generators may also provide it as an optional part of the API. When available, `getrandbits()` enables `randrange()` to handle arbitrarily large ranges.